# angular UI - Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application with more than 1500 pages. I am using angular UI Router for handling routing.

I want to know what is the good practice

1. Define all routes in app.js
2. Define routing per module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My personal recommendation would be to define routing per module as this will simplify the code for the maintainability perspective

From John papa's reference guide

> Define routes for views in the module where they exist. Each module
>   should contain the routes for the views in the module.
>
> Why?: Each module should be able to stand on its own.
>
> Why?: When removing a module or adding a module, the app will only
>   contain routes that point to existing views.
>
> Why?: This makes it easy to enable or disable portions of an
>   application without concern over orphaned routes.

you can refer John papa's angular guide [here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#routing)

Comment: Thanks Kushal for the link. I actually referred the same before posting question

Comment: Its a great guide for starting with angular!!

Comment: Yes.. Modularity the core of angular application